# What are the possible values of initial_payment_status in PayPal Express checkout?

Tags: express-checkout

I am getting IPN response:

My txn_type=recurring_payment_profile_created and initial_payment_status=Completed
I want to check whether payment is failed, to fire mail to buyer.

What are the possible values of **initial_payment_status** in PayPal Express checkout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no additional information in documentation for parameter "initial_payment_status" but the payment statuses are described in official paypal API documentation. Possible values are:

- **CANCELED** – The Preapproval agreement was cancelled
- **CREATED** – The payment request was received; funds will be transferred once the payment is approved
- **COMPLETED** – The payment was successful
- **INCOMPLETE** – Some transfers succeeded and some failed for a parallel payment or, for a delayed chained payment, secondary receivers have not been paid
- **ERROR** – The payment failed and all attempted transfers failed or all completed transfers were successfully reversed
- **REVERSALERROR** – One or more transfers failed when attempting to reverse a payment
- **PROCESSING** – The payment is in progress
- **PENDING** – The payment is awaiting processing